# Find W, X, Y, Z in terms of A, B, C, D.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A, B, C, D, W, X, Y, Z are square matrices and I is the identity matrix.

The inverse of: $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
I & C & B \\  
0 & I & A \\
0 & 0 & D
\end{array}\right]$$ 
is
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
I & W & X \\  
0 & I & Y \\
0 & 0 & Z
\end{array}\right]$$ 
Find  W, X, Y, Z in terms of A, B, C, D.

Ok so for this problem I know that multiplying the inverse of a matrix by the original matrix gives the identity matrix. Which should be:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

However I'm am not sure how to find the WXYZ matrix in terms of ABCD. To me they look the same.

Comment: The identity is $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
I &0 &0 \\  
0 & I & 0 \\
0 & 0 & I
\end{array}\right]$ not $\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Why is the identity matrix have "I" in the place of where I put 1? This is how I have learned in class, that it is just a diagonal streak of ones.

Comment: The point is that these are $3 \times 3$ [block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix): their entries are actually square matrices.

Comment: Are $A$ etc. just $1\times 1$ matrices?

Comment: They are all 3 x 3

Comment: @RobertIsrael oh I think I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply multiply the two matrices together and equate blocks:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
I & W & X \\  
0 & I & Y \\
0 & 0 & Z
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
I & C & B \\  
0 & I & A \\
0 & 0 & D
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & 0 \\  
0 & I & 0 \\
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}$$
This yields, after simplification, the matrix equations
$$W+C=0\qquad X+CY+BZ=0\qquad Y+AZ=0\qquad DZ=I$$
We get $Z=D^{-1}$, $W=-C$, $Y=-AD^{-1}$ and $X=(CA-B)D^{-1}$. The assumption is that $D$ is invertible.